# Почему парсер выдаёт ошибку:Cannot set property 'title' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

Всем здрасте . У меня вечные проблемы с парсерами . Коротко: при запуске кода вылетает ошибка

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined
```

У меня только один вопрос - почему когда я также само получаю параметр price всё норм , а когда тоже самое делаю с title выхоидт ошибка ?
Вот код:

```js
async function getPageContent(url){
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)
        const content = await page.content()
        await browser.close();
        //console.log(content);
        return content;
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
async function getElements(URL, options){
    try {
        const content = await getPageContent(URL)
        const $ = cheerio.load(content)
        const elements = [];
        $(options.TitleSel).each((idx, elem) =>{
            let title = $(elem).text();
            elements[idx].title = title;
        })
        $(options.PriceSel).each((idx, elem) =>{
            let price;
            if(!labir){
                price = $(elem).text();
                price = price.split(" ").join('')
                price = price.split("\n").join('')
                elements[idx].price = price;
            }else{
                price = `${$(elem).children().text()} руб`;
                elements[idx].price = price;
            }
        })
        $(options.UrlSel).each((idx, elem) =>{
            const URL = $(elem).closest('a');
            elements[idx].URL = URL;
        })
        console.log(elements);
        return(elements);
    }catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
let options = {
    TitleSel: '.card-title',
    PriceSel: '.card-price',
    UrlSel: '.product-info',
    labir:  false,
}
getElements('https://librarius.md/ru/search?search=Ведьмак', options)
```

Comment: Тут вообще ничего не должно работать, так как `elements=[]` не содержит ни одного объекта которому ты пытаешься установить свойство. А ошибка с `title` потому как `title` обрабатывается первым.

Comment: Понял ,  спасибо . Удачи !

Comment: Alexander Lonberg дай ответ на вопрос . Можешь написать что хочешь просто я тебе репутацию немного повышу )

Comment: это всего лишь банальная ошибка, для которой достаточно комментария. А если, как ты говоришь, _написать что хочешь(с)_, меня бы уже давно "закрыли" за "Оскорбление представителя власти, Клевету, Недостоверную информацию, Разжигание..., Бранную лексику" и т.п.